# 404 (Not Found) in ajax post url due to file upload

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

[image: Error i get in console is this]

```
jQuery("#myform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'editJobDesc' %}',
            data: formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Done");
            }
        });
    });
```

The code works perfectly fine in localhost but shows 404 url not found when hosted on server.

In django **views.py**:

```
profile = request.POST.get('profile')
jd = request.FILES.get('jd')
```

Django **urls.py**:

```
path('editJobDesc', views.editJobDesc, name="editJobDesc"),
```

**I found out that error is due to the file I am trying to upload using ajax. If I try to upload other inputs it works fine.**

I even tried appending file with formData but still I get the same error.

Comment: The single quotes within single quotes here `url:'{% url 'myurl' %}'` need to be changed.  Try using double quotes for the inner quotes like `url:'{% url "myurl" %}'`

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: I have also added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: it doesn't look like you fixed the nested quotes on the line I pointed out

Comment: `url:'{% url "editJobDesc" %}',` I changed the url on 6th line of my above code this way.

Comment: @TraceMalloc Found out that file upload is causing this problem, any idea why?

Comment: You may need to change the quotes to ```url:'{% url "editJobDesc" %}'```

Comment: @jaimish11 As I specified earlier the file upload is causing problem not the url.